# Changing a textView based on the value of a variable using coroutines in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine

I have a boolean variable **isConnected**. I want to change a textView on the basis of this variable.
For example

---

```
if (isConnected):
    textView text = a
else
    textView text = b
```

---

This code should be running throughout the program. I tried to implement this in Android Studio but the app was unable to load anything.

---

```
var isConnected = false
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    setStatusBar()

}

private fun setStatusBar() {
    CoroutineScope(Main).launch {
        while(true){
            checkConnection()
        }
    }
}

@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
private fun checkConnection() {
    CoroutineScope(Main).launch {
        if(!isConnected){
            status.text = "Disconnected"
        }
        else{
            status.text = "Connected"
        }
    }
}
```

---

As I change the value of isConnected, I want the app to change the text present in the status textview,
Can someone tell me why my code is not working?

Comment: The infinite loop in the main thread is disastrous, it never finishes execution so no other coroutine gets launched into it. I'd suggest to add delays, or Observer is more conservative as suggested by the answer by @ApacheOne.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a good practice too use infinite loops, Use Mutable LiveData to easily achieve this thing. You have to create a MutableLiveData variable isConnected of type Boolean and observer it value for changes to modify the text accordingly.

Variable declaration:

```
private val isConnected:MutableLiveData<Boolean> = MutableLiveData(false)
```

Now in onCreate observe it for changes:

```
   isConnected.observe(this,Observer {
         newValue -> 
                 if(!newValue){
                   status.text = "Disconnected"
                  }
                else{
                   status.text = "Connected"
                }     
})
```

Now to set the value use the below syntax:

```
isConnected.postValue(true)
```

Comment: The variable declaration was giving some errors but worked after changing the declaration to private var isConnected: MutableLiveData<Boolean> = MutableLiveData(). Thank You